# VBA With two columns if column 1 is a duplicate and column 2 is not give error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

**Example data:**

```
Pin name  voltage
V3V   3.3
V3V   3.3
V3V   3.3
V3V   4
VIN   58
VDR   6.5
VDREXT    6.5
V3V   3.3
```

**desired output:**

```
Bus Name voltage
V3V      3.3
VIN      58
VDR      6.5
VDREXT   6.5
```

I am having a hard time figuring out the best way to do this.
Would i use dictionary, a collection, or just two arrays to do this?
I need to error if a pin name is a duplicate but it has a different voltage
than the rest of the same pin names.

Comment: Line 4 in the example data should pop an error.

Comment: do looping .. but how if `V3V 4` came up first before `V3V 3.3` .. which one would be error ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess I need to give more background info.

Comment: I am trying to search a pin list and find out(summarize) how many power supplies i need. I only have 5 total power supplies. I don't have anyway to know the correct voltages. I just need to error if they have same pin name but different voltage. Pin list could be 2 pins to 3000+ pins long. So, I could have lots of repeat pin names.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a list of correct values for each name? Then you could just compare them using formula.

Comment: I don't have any way to tell what are correct values except by what is given. So, I need to error if i see a duplicate pin name with a different voltage. That way the person providing the info can check to see if he made a typo or copy paste error.

Comment: I came up with a code that delte duplicates, comparing current cell and cell below. It works good as long as data is sorted. So my question is if you can sort all data by pin name?